# Powershell script to locate only files starting with specified letters and ending with .csv

Tags: powershell, glob

```
cd 'A:\P\E\D'
$files = Get-ChildItem . *.CSV -rec

ForEach ($file in $files) {
    (Get-Content $file -Raw) | ForEach-Object { 
      *some simple code*
    } | Set-Content $file
    }
```

How to modify this powershell script to locate only files starting with letters A/a to O/o and ending with .csv in specified directory cd?

I thought the solution below would work, but the test file M_K_O_X.CSV stored in the cd directory was not found and modified. The solution above will find and modify the file. It's possible that I have the regex expression wrong or the problem is somewhere else? I tried also this regex -- "[A-O]*.*.CSV"

```
cd 'A:\P\E\D'
$files = Get-ChildItem . -rec | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "[a-oA-O]*.*.CSV" }

ForEach ($file in $files) {
    (Get-Content $file -Raw) | ForEach-Object { 
      *some simple code*
    } | Set-Content $file
    }
```

Comment: Just try `$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'A:\P\E\D' -Filter '*.csv' -File -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^[a-o]' }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your [wildcard pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.3), seems like you have an extra `*.` that shouldn't be there:

```bash
'M_K_O_X.CSV' -like '[a-oA-O]*.*.CSV' # False
'M_K_O_X.CSV' -like '[a-oA-O]*.CSV'   # True
```

In this case you could simply use the [`-Include` Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2#-include) which supports character ranges. Also PowerShell is case insensitive by default, `[a-oA-O]*.CSV` can be reduced to `[a-o]*.CSV`:

```bash
Get-ChildItem 'A:\P\E\D' -Recurse -Include '[a-o]*.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ | Get-Content -Raw) | ForEach-Object { 
        # *some simple code*
    } | Set-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but for some reason the file is still unedited after applying the script. I tried removing  *. from the wildcard pattern and also replacing with the code you provided. I will try other options tomorrow. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @storm97 what if you run `Get-ChildItem 'A:\P\E\D' -Recurse -Filter *.csv | ? { $_.BaseName -match '^[a-o]' }` ? Does that find the file?

Comment: The error was on my side, I had a badly set file path. I only modified that wildcard pattern and the script for two test files worked.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, I would use the standard wildcard -Filter to filter for all files with a .csv extension.
Then pipe to a Where-Object clause in which you can use regex `-match`

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'A:\P\E\D' -Filter '*.csv' -File -Recurse | 
         Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^[a-o]' }

foreach ($file in $files) {
    # switch `-Raw` makes Get-Content return a single multiline string, so no need for a loop
    $content = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw 
      # *some simple code manipulating $content*
    $content | Set-Content -Path $file.FullName
}
```

However, if these are valid csv files, I would not recommend using a pure textual manipulation on them, instead use `Import-Csv -Path $file.FullName` and work on the properties on each of the objects returned.